# Memory representation of functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Functions are treated as objects in javascript. I'm still not able to visualize and relate the things. What is going under the hood. I've written some code and drawn a memory representation according to my understanding.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sayHi() {
    var score=12;
    console.log("Hi! the score is " +score);
  }
  sayHi();
  var sayHi2 = sayHi;
  sayHi2();
  var sayHi3=sayHi;
  sayHi3.score=24;
  sayHi();
</script>
```

I thought `sayHi3.score=24` would change `score=12` to `score=24`. But It did not change. Help me visualize how things are working here.
[image]

I couldn't find any book which explains js like that.

Comment: your function sayHi() will always return "test2.html:7 Hi! the score is 12"

Comment: But I changed the value of `score` using `sayHi3.score=24`.

Comment: Functions are treated as objects but `score` is not a property of `sayHi` that is way the `sayHi3.score = 24` won't affect it.

Comment: you declared score again "var score=12";

Comment: When you're calling the sayHi function, you are declaring ```var score = 12```. For function 3, where you're defining ```sayHi3.score = 24```, it will be stored in the constructor. Try checking ```sayHi.prototype``` object. There under constructore you'll find the score you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the given memory representation holds good for 'functions as objects'. You've a pointer in the stack which will point to the actual function object in heap. But function objects are slightly different from normal objects.

See the code below

```
function sayHi() {
    var score=12;
    console.log("Hi! the score is " +score);
}
```

`var score=12` is a local variable of `function sayHi()`. Beginners like me may confuse it with property. So first thing, local variable and property are two different things. Since functions are treated as objects, you can add properties to the function objects.

The code below adds a new property to the function object

```
function sayHi() {
    var score=12;
    console.log("Hi! the score is " +score);
}
sayHi.newProp='hello'; // Adding property to the function object
```

So here, `var score=12` is a local variable while `newProp='hello'` is a property.
To confirm whether the property was successfully added or not. Lets run the code below. I'll create a new pointer which will point to the same function object where `sayHi` was pointing to.

```
function sayHi() {
    var score=12;
    console.log("Hi! the score is " +score);
}
sayHi.newProp='hello';

/*Create a new pointer pointing to the same object*/
var obj=sayHi;
console.log(obj.newProp);
```

Output

> Hi! the score is 12
>
> hello

`obj.newProp` prints `hello` because `sayHi.newProp='hello';` was able to add a new property i.e. `newProp` to the function object.

[image: We can roughly represent this as follows:]

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function you are declaring the score to 12. So every time the function calls the score is 12.

If you want setting the variable with different value you can do something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var score=12; // move out from the function
  function sayHi() {
    console.log("Hi! the score is " +score);
  }
  sayHi(); // score = 12
  var sayHi2 = sayHi;
  sayHi2(); // score is still 12
  var sayHi3=sayHi;
  score=24; // now score is 24
  sayHi3(); // print 24
</script>
```

Didn't quite understand what is your goal. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the sayHi function, you are declaring `var score = 12`. For function 3, where you're defining `sayHi3.score = 24`, it will be stored in the constructor. Try checking `sayHi.prototype` object. There under constructor you'll find the score you created.

[image]